# Having text not showing background in td element

Tags: css

I have td cells that have individual background images in them. The problem im facing is that the empty parts of a text string shows the background.

For example, lets say i have the letter O on a red background. Now I want the middle of the O to be white while the surrounding area should be red.

What I have tried to far is make the text as display: block but that did not get me what i wanted.

Is this even possible with only css?

Comment: display:inline-block to text apply background for that...

Comment: *Now I want the middle of the O to be white while the surrounding area should be red.* No, this is not possible with only CSS.

Comment: No, that isn't how fonts work. The center of a letter isn't a separate part that can be colored. The closest thing you can do would be to make the element with the text a block element and set its `background-color` but that will make a block of color that surrounds the text, not just fills in the circles of individual letters.

Comment: Thenks CodingWithSpike, that was enogh! Perfect